# Captcha Refresh Image technique

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha

I have a Update panel it has a captcha image.when validation fire i need to reload the captcha image.I need only captcha image reload when validation fires.

### Code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">

    <ajax:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptManager1"
        AsyncPostBackTimeout="300" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </ajax:ScriptManager>
    <ajax:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            //Some other textboxes there
            <div>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Class="captcha" runat="server" 
                    Height="60px"
                    ImageUrl="~/Captcha.aspx" Width="210px" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCaptchaMessage">
                </asp:Label>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" 
                OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajax:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

### Code behind

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some code here.when validation fires. it shows the error message and
    // i need to refresh/reload the captcha image
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    {
        //need to reload captcha image here.
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need only captcha image", why ? what else is change ?

Comment: @Aristos I have another textbox control there. i dont need to refresh those items.

Comment: If your other textbox change, then there is the issue...